# Using the mean value theorem to prove inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, derivatives

> Using the Mean Value Theorem, show that for any $t>0$, $$\left|e^{-x^2/2t}-e^{-y ^2/2t}\right|\leqslant \frac{|x-y|}{t}$$ for all $x,y$ with $|x|,|y|\leqslant 1$.

**My attempt.**

Without loss of generality, assume $y<x$ and define $f(z)=e^{-z^2/2t}$ for any $t>0$ and $z\in [y,x]\subseteq[-1,1]$. Now, $f$ is continuous on $[y,x]$ and differentiable on $(y,x)$ so by the MVT there exists a $c\in(y,x)\subseteq(-1,1)$ such that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}.$$ So there exists a $c\in(y,x)$ such that $$\frac{e^{-x^2/2t}-e^{-y^2/2t}}{x-y}=\frac{-e^{-c^2/2t}c}{t}.$$ After this, I don't know how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Study (bound) the expression $-e^{-c^2/2t}c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that: $|-e^{-c^2/2t}\cdot c| \leq 1\cdot |c| \leq 1$ because $|c| \leq |y| \leq 1$

Answer (score 2):

Are we allowed to propose solutions which use only elementary tools? Then note that the absolute value of the derivative of the function $u\mapsto\mathrm e^{-u}$ is at most $1$ on $u\geqslant0$ hence the most basic version of the mean value theorem yields $$\left|e^{-x^2/2t}-e^{-y ^2/2t}\right|\leqslant1\cdot\left|\frac{x^2}{2t}-\frac{y^2}{2t}\right|=\left|x-y\right|\cdot\left|x+y\right|\cdot\frac1{2t}.$$ By hypothesis, $\left|x+y\right|\leqslant|x|+|y|\leqslant2$, hence the RHS is at most $\left|x-y\right|\cdot2/(2t)=\left|x-y\right|/t$, QED.

More generally, if $|x|\leqslant M$ and $|y|\leqslant M$, then  $$\left|e^{-x^2/2t}-e^{-y ^2/2t}\right|\leqslant M\cdot\left|x-y\right|\cdot\frac1t.$$